# Nginx: Setup a Reverse Proxy Server that Listens to a Port Other than 80

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup a reverse proxy server that listens for incoming connections on port 8080 (or any port other than 80) and forwards them to port 3000, but whatever I do I can't get it to work. Here is the `nginx.conf` file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that when I set the port to 80, everything works fine. Also, when I set up a static file server on any port, Nginx serves the files just fine. This issue occurs only when setting up a reverse proxy server.

**EDIT**

- With Port 80:

  - Curl: Prints out the HTML of the desired page.
  - access_log: `MY_IP_ADDRESS - - [03/May/2017:03:05:45 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 704 "-" "curl/7.49.1"`
- With port 8080:

  - Curl: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to iceacademic.com port 8080: Operation timed out`
  - access_log: nothing
  - error_log: nothing

Comment: On the surface that looks ok. If you change 8080 to 80 it works? Please change config to 80, restart, curl, and show us the access log. Then change back to 8080, curl, show us the curl output and if appropriate the access and error log. Demonstrate the problem, don't just say "something is wrong". Please edit your question to provide the additional information, then you can comment so I know there is new information.

Comment: @Tim Yes that's correct if I change 8080 to 80 it'll work. Please see my updated question

Comment: `Operation timed out` is a strong indicator for a firewall problem.

Comment: Have you checked that nginx actually listens to port 8080 after you have restarted it? If yes, then you need to check your firewall rules.

Comment: As people have said, "netstat -anp | grep 8080" to see if Nginx is listening is what you should do next. Of course you're restarting the Nginx service after config changes.